# In SDL, what is the difference between using a Surfaces and a Renderer?

Tags: sdl

I am new to SDL and I've been following some tutorials; in one tutorial he used Surfaces (a window surface and image surface) and a BlitSurface function to draw images without using any renderer (used SDL Image library for JPG, PNG etc.).

And in another tutorial, he used a Renderer.

What's the difference between those two? It seemed to me they do the same thing but I'm assuming if they were the same, one wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 15):

This is fairly well documented in the SDL1 to SDL2 [Migration Guide](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#Overview_of_new_features).

Essentially, `SDL_Surface` is a tool for CPU side blit rendering, where as `SDL_Renderer` takes advantage of hardware acceleration, and performs the rendering on the GPU. `SDL_Renderer` provides an abstraction over several APIs and even offers a fallback CPU-side implementation if no other implementation suits your platform (unlikely).

There are very few reasons for using `SDL_Surface`s for rendering these days, except if you 100% know what you are doing (and are perhaps writing a low resolution raytracer that runs on the CPU?). `SDL_Renderer` and its `SDL_Texture` is a much better performing choice if you don't need CPU side access to individual pixels.